# Generic type on Typescript class can be omitted

Tags: typescript, class, generics

Using Typescript with default compiler options is pretty strict on what is allowed or not - like null values, class attributes not being initiated in constructor. But when it comes to generics, it is possible to define a generic type for a class and then create a new class without specifying the type!

```
class Foo<T> {
    bar(item: T): void {
        console.log('typeof T: ', typeof item)
    }
}

const foo1 = new Foo<string>() // T specified
foo1.bar('hello')
foo1.bar(6) // error TS2345: Argument of type '6' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

const foo2 = new Foo() // T missing
foo2.bar('hello')
foo2.bar(6) // works with no complaint
```

Is that possible to consider `new Foo()` as being a wrong statement?

As specified above I am using the default compiler options which would not allow to add an extra attribute `a: T` which would never be initialised.

Answer (score 5):

You can't make the omission of `T` on the constructor an error (well you probably can but you would need some conditional type magic and a constructor with at least one argument)

You can make the class unusable if no argument is supplied by using a default for the type parameter. A default of `never` will do the trick.

```
class Foo<T = never> {
    bar(item: T): void {
        console.log('typeof T: ', typeof item)
    }
}

const foo1 = new Foo<string>() // T specified
foo1.bar('hello')
foo1.bar(6) // error TS2345: Argument of type '6' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

const foo2 = new Foo() // T missing
foo2.bar('hello') // err
foo2.bar(6) // err
```

You can also use a constructor overload and tuples in rest parameters to make a constructor that will give an error if you omit the type parameter (ie the type parameter is `never`)

```
class Foo<T = never> {
    constructor(...a: T extends never ? ['No T was specified']:[])
    constructor() {

    }
    bar(item: T): void {
        console.log('typeof T: ', typeof item)
    }
}


const foo1 = new Foo<string>() // T specified
foo1.bar('hello')
foo1.bar(6) // error TS2345: Argument of type '6' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

const foo2 = new Foo() // T missing, error!
foo2.bar('hello')//err
foo2.bar(6) //err
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers, I'd like to point out that TSLint has a rule specifically against this case: [`no-inferred-empty-object-type`](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-inferred-empty-object-type/)

Enabling this rule will make TSLint complain about when TypeScript infers `{}` as a generic (similar to the `noImplicitAny` compiler flag, only for generics).

This seems to be exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

> it is possible to define a generic type for a class and then create a new class without specifying the type!

[Of course, it's called *type argument inference*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html):

> that is, we want the compiler to set the value of T for us automatically based on the type of the argument we pass in:

so

> Is that possible to consider new Foo() as being a wrong statement?

No, because the compiler is probably either setting `T` as `any` or `string | number` based on the code you've already written.  So `T`is completely valid.

taking a look at your code:

```
const foo2 = new Foo() // T missing
foo2.bar('hello')
foo2.bar(6) // works with no complaint
```

Why would it complain, the compiler has to infer a type so it's looking at **all** usages to infer a valid type.  After all what is the difference between the previous code and the following:

```
const foo3 = new Foo() // T missing
foo3.bar(6) 
foo3.bar('hello') // works with no complaint
```

Only the order of operations.  Why should the compiler assume that only the first usage of a method determine the type of `T`?  What if it was the following:

```
const foo3 = new Foo() // T missing
if (someValueOrBooleanReturningFunction) {
  foo3.bar(6) 
}
foo3.bar('hello') // works with no complaint
```

Then what? Maybe it could or maybe it couldn't determine the value of the `if`, but either way since the a type isn't specified, the compiler has to determine what `T` is.

Comment: The example you link to is at a function level. The point of defining a type at the class level is to prevent this type of error. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Sure, but you didn't specify a type for the class, so it still has to infer a type.

Comment: So my question I guess is: Is there a way to disable the type inference for a class?

Comment: Yeah, specify T, as in your first example or use a generic constraint.